# Do matrice of eigen vectors reduce to the identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to understand whether a matrix of eigen vectors links to the identity matrix.  My logic is:

1. The null space of $A$, denoted $N(A)$ is a set of vectors that satisfy $A x = 0$
2. Suppose A is a matrix of eigen vectors $[ v_1 v_2 ... v_n ]$, then $N(A) = 0$
3. $N(I) = 0$ where I is the identity matrix.
4. Since $N(A) = N(rref(A)) = N(I)$, can I conclude that $rref(A) = I \; \forall A$?

Comment: I don't understand $2$

Comment: @Belgi 2 means put the eigen vectors of a matrix together to form matrix A.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are asking if every matrix with a given rank is equivalent (via rref) to the identity matrix of the same rank, right? In that case the answer is no.

For example, consider the matrix A with with $a_{ij}= 0$ if $i\neq j$ and $a_{ii}\neq 0$ with at least one of them different from the others.

If you're familiar with the concept of linear transformation and their relation with matrices the answer can be thought in that context: Every injective linear transformation satisfies that $N(A)=\{0\}$ (more commonly $kerA$), but obviously not all of them are the identity (taking the matrix to its rref is only a change of basis, so this viewpoint is certainly more general).

Comment: My question is $rref(A) = I$ for all square full rank matrix $A$.  After some study, I think the answer is yes.  I think you proved that $N(A)=0$ doesn't imply $A=I$, which I agree.